# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I have teh following code in HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using MovieApp.Models;
namespace MovieApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private MoviesDBEntities _db = new MoviesDBEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(_db.MovieSet.ToList());

        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View(_db.MovieSet);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Create 

        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();

        }

        //

        // POST: /Home/Create 

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] Movie movieToCreate)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View();

            _db.AddToMovieSet(movieToCreate);

            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            var movieToEdit = (from m in _db.MovieSet

                               where m.Id == id

                               select m).First();

            return View(movieToEdit);

        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Edit/5 

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]

        public ActionResult Edit(Movie movieToEdit)
        {

            var originalMovie = (from m in _db.MovieSet

                                 where m.Id == movieToEdit.Id

                                 select m).First();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View(originalMovie);

            _db.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalMovie.EntityKey.EntitySetName, movieToEdit);

            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }
}
```

I have created a Details view with the following code:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            Id:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Id) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Title:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Title) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Director:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Director) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            DateReleased:
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", Model.DateReleased)) %>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

However when I run it, I get an error saying that Object reference not set to an instance of an object on this line: `<%= Html.Encode(Model.Id) %>` I'm presuming I'm missing something in the HomeController.cs under the Details ActionResult. But what?

Thanks.

EDIT 2:

Adding this to the code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    //return View();

    var movieToView = (from m in _db.MovieSet

                       where m.Id == id

                       select m).First();

    return View(movieToView);
```

Fixes the problem. But why do I need to specify this? Does return View() not just show it?? and why?

Comment: Model is null.. post code for MovieApp.Models where it's probably being declared and initialized and we'll try to see what might be wrong.

Comment: check Exception.StackTrace - if you're running in debug mode, it will contain the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your _db.MovieSet property is returning a null value. I would put a breakpoint in your debugger in the controllers details method to check this.

EDIT: Looking at you code it appears form other methods that your _db.MovieSet property is a collection rather that an object. I am just guessing but as your details action has an id parameter I would think that using linq to return an object from that collection would help. Something along the lines of:

```
return View(_db.MovieSet.Single(m => m.Id == id));
```

It would probably be an idea to assign this to a variable and check for a null value before passing to the view to catch any null value exceptions and handle then gracefully:

```
var movieSet = _db.MovieSet.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
if(moviesSet != null)
    return View(movieSet);
else
    return View("Error");
```

Make sure your detail view has the correct model associated with it.

Comment: All the other views such as Index, Edit and Create all work, it's just the Details one that does not work.

Comment: Do I need to add additional code to the `return View();` under the Details?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything thou I'm not an expert, Looking at the **public ActionResult Edit(Movie movieToEdit)**  it see seems like a perfect spot for a null return.

Answer (score 0):

This provided the answer for me, apparently the naming convention is incorrect within the model. Use the edmx entity model name. e.g _db.**Movies**.ToList() The thread also contains the source code.
http://forums.asp.net/post/4051978.aspx

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. While the link you provided may have the information to answer the question please note that link only answers are not permitted on SO. This is to prevent links going dead in future. Links as references are very much encouraged but please add all pertinent information in future.